# modal bottom sheet reusable class missing "State build" method

Tags: flutter, modal-dialog, bottom-sheet, reusability

I am trying to create a custom bottom sheet class to be re-usable, but it gives me the error of missing "State build" method. I know that I may include the @override method, but I have checked other responses like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71582707/how-to-make-reusable-modal-bottom-sheet), and I did not see the build method.

```
class ModalBottomSheet extends StatefulWidget {
  final Function()? onPressed;

  const ModalBottomSheet({Key? key, this.onPressed}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<ModalBottomSheet> createState() => _ModalBottomSheetState();
  }
  
  //error here 
  class _ModalBottomSheetState extends State<ModalBottomSheet> {
   modal(context){
    showModalBottomSheet(
        context: context,
        isScrollControlled: true,
        backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
        builder: (BuildContext context) {
          return Container(
           
            ),
          );
        });
      }
    }
```

**EDIT:**

```
class ModalBottomSheet {
void modal(context) {
Function(int)? onPressed;

showModalBottomSheet(
    context: context,
    isScrollControlled: true,
    backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
    builder: (BuildContext context) {
      return Container(
        height: 200,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: Colors.white,
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
              topLeft: Radius.circular(20), topRight: Radius.circular(20)),
        ),
        child: Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
          child: Column(
            children: [
          TextButton(
                onPressed: (1) {
                  onPressed?.call();
                },
                child: Text(
                  'CAMERA',
                ),
              ),
              
              TextButton(
                onPressed: (2) {
                  onPressed?.call();
                },
                child: Text(
                  'GALLERY',
                ),
              ),
```

This is the **Main screen** where to show the custom modal sheet:

```
ModalBottomSheet.modal(context,
                          onPressed: (index){
                            if(index == 1){
                              pickImage(ImageSource.camera);
                            }else{
                              pickImage(ImageSource.gallery);
                            }
                          });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are extending the `StatefulWidget`, which requires you to override the `build` method. Instead, you can create a class or mixin that doesn't extend `Widget`, it will have a method that shows modal and requires `BuildContext` as a function parameter.

```
class ModalBottomSheet {
  void modal(context) {
    showModalBottomSheet(
      context: context,
      isScrollControlled: true,
      backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return ...
      },
    );
  }
}
```

**Edit:**

You can also pass other parameters to this function, as `void Function()? onPressed`.

```
class ModalBottomSheet {
  static void modal(BuildContext context, void Function()? onPressed) {
    showModalBottomSheet(
      context: context,
      isScrollControlled: true,
      backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return ...;
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: ok nice. but can i still pass function onPressed? because now it gives me error

Comment: ok maybe just pass ```Function()? onPressed``` and then ```onPressed?.call()``` without the "widget" keyword

Comment: you pass it as function parameter `void modal(BuildContext context, Function()? onPressed)`

Comment: Thanks, nice explanation. However i changed the class as you suggested but when i try to access the class method using "ModalBottomSheet." i cannot display the method.

Comment: @Giovanni make the function static `static void modal()`, so you can access it as `ModalBottomSheet.modal()`

Comment: No actually it worked just now, passing the Buildcontext to ```modal```. but how can i access the ```onPressed``` function? Right now I wrote "ModalBottomSheet.modal(context)"

Comment: @Giovanni I edited the answer, now it include onPressed parameter as well.

Comment: Nice! works like a charms! Now i was able to pass index and pass function between different buttons. Thanks again!